# only top button sliding down works css jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

     <style>
         #Slider {

         }
         #Actual {
             background: silver;
             color: White;
             padding: 20px;
         }
         .slideup, .slidedown {
             max-height: 0;            
             overflow-y: hidden;
             -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
             -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
             transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in-out;
         }
         .slidedown {            
             max-height: 60px ;                    
         }    
     </style>
   </head>

   <body>

 <%
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
 %>  

     <div class="container" style="padding: 40px">
       <a id="Trigger">Trigger Slideup/SlideDown</a>
       <div id="Slider" class="slideup">
       <div id="Actual">
                 Hello World Text
             </div>
       </div>
     </div>
 <%} %>

     <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
     <script>

         $("#Trigger").click(function () {
           $("#Slider").toggleClass("slidedown slideup");
           //  if ($("#Slider").hasClass("slideup"))
           //    $("#Slider").removeClass("slideup").addClass("slidedown");
           //  else
           //      $("#Slider").removeClass("slidedown").addClass("slideup");
         });
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Hi guys!
I like to make all three banner work but only top one works. 
any idea what is wrong with this?

[This is what is look like on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmhpF.jpg)

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

***text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text******text***v

Comment: You are using a loop to create 3 divs, each one with a nested div (#Slider and #Trigger) with the same ID. IDs must be unique. Use classes.

Comment: Oh my god you are right ! thanks man! apprieciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  <div class="container" style="padding: 40px">
>    <a id="Trigger">Trigger Slideup/SlideDown</a>
>    <div id="Slider" class="slideup">
>    <div id="Actual">
>              Hello World Text
>          </div>
>    </div>
>  </div>
> ```

Each of your banners will have elements with id's `Trigger` `Slider` `Actual` (three of each). `id` attribute should have a unique value in the document. jQuery will select the first item with a given id.

First we replace `id` with `class`.

`$(this).siblings(".Slider")` is to make sure we are selecting the `Slider`
in the same container the `Target` is in

```js
$(".Trigger").click(function () {
  $(this).siblings(".Slider").toggleClass("slidedown slideup");;
});
```

```css
.slideup { background-color: red }
.slidedown { background-color: gold }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding: 40px">
   <a class="Trigger">Trigger Slideup/SlideDown</a>
   <div class="Slider slideup">
   <div class="Actual">
             Hello World Text
         </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="padding: 40px">
   <a class="Trigger">Trigger Slideup/SlideDown</a>
   <div class="Slider slideup">
   <div class="Actual">
             Hello World Text
         </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="padding: 40px">
   <a class="Trigger">Trigger Slideup/SlideDown</a>
   <div class="Slider slideup">
   <div class="Actual">
             Hello World Text
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

*Note: I'm changing color instead of sliding up and down*

Comment: i really appreciate all you comment